# Integrate Stripe Payment Element in Next.js 13 App Router TypeScript Project

Tags: typescript, element, payment, next.js13

UPDATE: Thank you for your reply, Александр Невский!

Now I am trying to get this to work.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-stripe-typescript

I can't get past this error:

Failed to compile.

./app/actions/getStripe.ts
ReactServerComponentsError:

You're importing a component that needs next/headers. That only works in a Server Component but one of its parents is marked with "use client", so it's a Client Component.

,-[/vercel/path0/app/actions/getStripe.ts:3:1]
3 | import type { Stripe } from 'stripe'
4 |
5 | import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'
6 | import { headers } from 'next/headers'
: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
7 |
8 | import { CURRENCY } from '@/config'
9 | import { formatAmountForStripe } from '@/utils/stripe-helpers'
`----

One of these is marked as a client entry with "use client":
./app/actions/getStripe.ts
./app/components/ElementsForm.tsx

> Build failed because of webpack errors

Works perfect locally, but when I try to deploy to Vercel, I can never get past that error.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Thanks, again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use serverActions to replace handler with function

Possibly you need to use 'use client' directive in your checkout form, beacause of state and onChange handlers.

Also you can use StripeElements from '@stripe/stripe-js' package, it provides more flexible api compared to stripe react package

```
    const stripeElements = useRef<StripeElements>(null) 

    const FormVisible = async () => {
    
    const stripe = await getStripe();
    const response = await fetch('/api/stripe/create-payment-intent', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(NotImportantBodyToQuestionContext),
    });
    //get client secret, it stored in payment intent
    const {clientSecret} = await response.json();


    const appearance = {
        theme: 'stripe',
    };
    
    stripeElements.current = stripe!.elements({appearance, clientSecret});

    const paymentElementOptions = {
        layout: 'tabs',
    };

    // @ts-ignore
    const paymentElement = stripeElements.current.create('payment', paymentElementOptions);
    paymentElement.mount('#payment-element'); //or any other id
    setloader(false)
}
```

i hope it helps, feel free to ask questions

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

Now I am trying to get this to work.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-stripe-typescript

I can't get past this error:

Comment: FWIW, [this](https://vercel.com/guides/getting-started-with-nextjs-typescript-stripe) tutorial explains how to do something similar, and it worked for me. (Note, the example repo accompanying the tutorial has changed since the tutorial was written so you have to look at the example repo at the time of [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/f7baa56792cf8566954f762b961260a00c476994/examples/with-stripe-typescript) commit.)